# Access child class of a component using scss

Tags: html, css, angular, sass

I have a `my-grid` component, which is used inside a `parent-component` as

**Parent Component**

```
<my-grid id="myGrid" [ngClass]="'temp'"></my-grid>
```

which is rendered as HTML below

```
<my-grid id="myGrid" class="temp e-control e-grid e-lib e-gridhover e-responsive e-default e-droppable e-tooltip e-keyboard" >
   <div class="e-groupdroparea e-lib e-droppable e-draggable" tabindex="-1">
      XYZ
    </div>
</my-grid>
```

I have added conditional class `temp` dynamically using `ngClass`. The **ParentComponent** has `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None`. and in **parent-component.scss** I have:

```
parent-comp {
  my-grid {
    .temp {
      &.e-groupdroparea.e-lib.e-droppable.e-draggable{
        margin-left: 265px !important;
      }
    }    
    // below styling works
    /**.e-groupdroparea.e-lib.e-droppable.e-draggable{
      * margin-left: 265px !important;
      *}
    */
  }
}
```

The styling does not work when I try to add it using `.temp{ }` of scss. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Should be my-grid { &.temp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
parent-comp {
    .temp {
      .e-groupdroparea.e-lib.e-droppable.e-draggable{
        margin-left: 265px !important;
      }
    } 
}
```

it should work.